# Push into Assembla Git repository

Tags: eclipse, git, assembla

I pulled fresh copy of my project from Assembla git repository and restructured the whole project at my system and deleted some of useless classes and files from the project as well.
Now when i push it back into remote repository from my eclipse it does not work because of confliction of whole structures on both sides.

Please suggest what to do to push fresh copy of project in remote git repository on assembla.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your repo at Assembla, in setting you can allow a force push. This is considered to be a dangerous push as you are rewriting history and will cause problems if others have your repo as well.

Once you have done that you can do a force push by adding -f to your push command:
`git push -f origin master`

This will replace the remote side with your master - completely, no merging or conflicts.

A less destructive way to push your commits is to pull the repo first and merge in the changes from the remote. You might want to consider rebasing since you are changing the structure so much, this will apply your changes on top of the remote changes.